# Question too broad, how do I get more details?

Tags: discussion

I asked a kind of simple question recently and it was closed as "too broad". [Virtualization: Assign graphics card to vm and back to host when the vm exits. - Is this possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/1048177/virtualization-assign-graphics-card-to-vm-and-back-to-host-when-the-vm-exits)

But I'm having trouble understanding why/how is it "too broad". I'd say you could legitimately answer the question with a simple "yes" or "no". I mean, sure, some hints on how it could be achieved would be nice, but I don't see how the question would be "too broad".

So how do I get more details for why the question is "too broad"?

> too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or
>   has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format
>
> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer
>   set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: If a question can be answered by a "yes" or "no" answer that is a sign there is a problem with the question.

Comment: @Ramhound But can such a question too broad?

Comment: I think "Yes" and "No" questions are often indeed broad in nature.  It means the scope of the question has not been reduced.  While a question can have a wide scope, it still has to solve a problem, and normally that problem has specific elements.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, people would add a comment explaining why the question is too broad. However, that's completely optional.

There is really nothing you can do to get people to provide more details. I would recommend asking the friendly folks in our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access).

In your specific case, the operating system and the hypervisor you're using would be a good start to make the question more answerable.

Comment: Hmm, but I didn't really have a specific hypervisor or OS in mind. I mean, sure, a Unix based OS or Windows would be nice, but I really don't care about the hypervisor as long as it would be able to the job.

Comment: The chat room gladly answered my question. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: @Forivin - you have to understand the hypervisor you choose makes a huge difference.  You having a specific hypervisor or at least the TYPE of hypervisor would have helped.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to know if it would be possible. I had no specific hypervisor on my mind. I just wanted to know if it was possible. Now that I know it is possible if you are on Linux, it might make sense to ask a more specific question. But if I had asked "would it be possible on win 7 using hyperv" the answer would have been no... And that would have helped whom? The answerer maybe, but certainly not me.

Comment: "Is it possible" with which Hypervisor?  You asked the reason it was closed for being bro do provided a possible reason. Your question isn't a "Yes" or "No" question.